# Merging multiple tables using SQL in CartoDB

Tags: sql, carto

I have 5 separate tables in CartoDB each with a varying number of columns, but all containing these 4 columns (the_geom, name, type, unit_code). I want to merge them all into 1 new table and get rid of most of the columns. I figured out that UNION ALL will get rid of the columns I don't need in the end, but I can't see how to merge the tables using SQL. Whenever I try UNION ALL it doesn't want to work. I've also seen that sometimes I need to write UNION_ALL with the underscore to make it work? Here's my sample code:

```
SELECT the_geom, name, type, unit_code FROM points_of_interest
UNION ALL
SELECT the_geom, altname, descriptio, unitcode FROM arch_visitor_centers
UNION ALL
SELECT the_geom, name FROM arch_trailheads
UNION ALL
SELECT the_geom, bldg_name FROM arch_restrooms
UNION ALL
SELECT the_geom, name FROM arch_parking
UNION ALL
SELECT the_geom, name, FROM arch_campgrounds
UNION ALL
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. I've made some minor code formatting changes, so its easier to see - you can do that yourself using the {} button on future questions. When you say "doesn't want to work", it can help a lot to describe what happens instead, especially any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

So the quickest answer is that SQL expects the same dimension of columns in each statement you try to do a UNION on. So all the first column of your SQL statements should match what you want to be in the first column of your result. Generally, they will also need to match in data type.

The column names themselves don't matter.

So to make yours work you'd do something like

```
SELECT the_geom, name, type, '' AS description, unit_code FROM points_of_interest
UNION ALL
SELECT the_geom, altname, '' AS type, descriptio, unitcode FROM arch_visitor_centers
UNION ALL
SELECT the_geom, name, '' AS type, '' as description, '' as unitcode FROM arch_trailheads
UNION ALL
SELECT the_geom, bldg_name, '' AS type, '' as description, '' as unitcode FROM arch_restrooms
UNION ALL
SELECT the_geom, name,'' AS type, '' as description, '' as unitcode FROM arch_parking
UNION ALL
SELECT the_geom, name,'' AS type, '' as description, '' as unitcode FROM arch_campgrounds
```

The result would contain

```
the_geom, name, type, description, unit_code
```

I'm assuming that type, name, description, and unit_code are all Text type variables. You can keep track of what table your rows came from by manually including a final column that just includes the table name aliased to a column. E.g.

```
SELECT the_geom, name, type, '' AS description, unit_code, 'points_of_interest' as source_table FROM points_of_interest
UNION ALL
SELECT the_geom, altname, '' AS type, descriptio, unitcode, 'arch_visitor_centers' as source_table FROM arch_visitor_centers
UNION ALL
SELECT the_geom, name, '' AS type, '' as description, '' as unitcode, 'arch_trailheads' as source_table FROM arch_trailheads
UNION ALL
SELECT the_geom, bldg_name, '' AS type, '' as description, '' as unitcode, 'arch_restrooms' as source_table FROM arch_restrooms
UNION ALL
SELECT the_geom, name,'' AS type, '' as description, '' as unitcode, 'arch_parking' as source_table FROM arch_parking
UNION ALL
SELECT the_geom, name,'' AS type, '' as description, '' as unitcode, 'arch_campgrounds' as source_table FROM arch_campgrounds
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, this code worked perfectly. So I guess in a situation such as this, the first SELECT query sets the column names for the following statements, is that the case?

Comment: the first statement sets what the column names will be in the response. the rest of the statements must select columns in the same order and type. so if the first column in the first statement is a string, the first column in the second statement must also be a string. that's all